# How to secure my data?

Tags: php, ftp, encryption

I offer a bunch of clients back of their cPanel account.
This is done by using FTP - they transfer the backups to an unique FTP account on my server, using the built-in backup function.

However, all those backups are stored unencrypted.

I paid a guy to make a php script that encrypt/decrypt backups, but it takes 5-7 minutes to encrypt 20MB of data - which I find too long time.

Any suggestions how to speed up the encryption, or am I doing it all wrong?

Comment: What OS is your server? You could use something like TrueCrypt and create an encrypted partition/folder and let your clients upload their stuff there.

Comment: How is the backup done, maybe it's better to do the encryption *before* the upload, if possible.

Comment: 5-7m to encrypt is a ludicrous amount of time. Unless it's doing a .tar.gz at the same time it's encrypting, something is very wrong with this guy's code.

Comment: They are running default cPanel and the backups are created using the default cpanel backup feature.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Transfer_Protocol) is insecure. Consider using something like [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy). If you're on a Linux server there are many strong encryption tools available.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the [SFTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol) protocol for secure uploads instead of FTP.

Furthermore you could use phpseclib's class [`Crypt_AES`](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/sym_crypt.html#sym_crypt_aes) to encrypt the uploaded files, which in my experience is one of the fastest pure PHP encryptions I've ever seen (around 1.5 minutes per 10 MB on a 2 GHz AMD, iirc. Heavily depends on your hardware, of course).

Comment: Thanks, will look into that and get back to you :)

Comment: Seems I got it down to ~2.5seconds for a 150KB file using a 1.8Ghz server. Which match the test in the end of this page:   http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/sym_crypt.html#sym_crypt_aes  . Will a bigger CPU speed up the encrypting time?

Comment: Hm, 2.5 secs/150 KB?. Did you use AES or Rijndael? AES is faster. Additionally enabling [mCrypt](http://php.net/mcrypt) could speed up things a bit. Also worth mentioning: have you tried compressing the file before encrypting it? Maybe the combo of both is faster than encrypting the uncompressed file. And yes, a faster CPU would of course encrypt faster^^

Comment: Used Rinjndael, the files im encrypting is already compressed. If I encrypt several files at the same time (using different scripts), will each encrypt using their own Core (if multicore)?

Comment: I cannot tell this for sure (my experience with admin stuff is limited), but afaik you'd need to have Apache worker (MPM) and a FastCGI daemon (mod_fastcgi or mod_fcgid) installed to take advantage of multicores in PHP.